# Code doesn't take three inputs and display three different results but takes one input and displays the same result three times

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

I'm just beginning to learn c and I'm confused about why my code only takes one input and displays the same result three times when it's supposed to take three inputs and display three different results. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b, c, d, result[3];
    
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    scanf("(%d+%d)x(%d-%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    result[i] = (a+b)*(c-d);
    }
    
    printf("%d %d %d\n", result[0], result[1], result[2]);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to take the inputs

```
(3+4)x(1-3)
(8+3)x(5-4)
(4+12)x(11-9)
```

and output

```
-14 11 32
```

Instead it only takes

```
(3+4)x(1-3)
```

and outputs

```
-14 -14 -14
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never checked the return value of scanf. It tells you whether the scan succeeded. Notice that your inputs each start on a new line but your scanf expects them all on one line.

Comment: from the 2nd line onwards scanf is expecting a `'('` but the input has a `'\n'` ==> https://ideone.com/XVH5PP

Comment: Read [Beginner's Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to skip the new line character  `'\n'` between the inputs that corresponds to the pressed key Enter  by placing a leading space in the format string

```
scanf(" (%d+%d)x(%d-%d)", &a, &b, &c, &d);
      ^^^
```

In general you should check whether a call of scanf was successful.

Comment: You don't need spaces before `%d` conversions because they skip white space anyway, whether you want them to or not.  OTOH, it might not be a bad idea to put a white space in the format string before each literal `(+)x-` so that ` ( 23 + 13 ) x ( 24 - 9 )` could be parsed successfully.  You might need to add a `%n` conversion at the end to check whether the last close parenthesis was read OK (or replace the last close parenthesis with `%c` and check that a close parenthesis was read).